# esbuild: How to use `loader: { '.css': 'text' }` in combination with `minify: true` to get minified CSS as embedded text?

Tags: esbuild

In my web project I import CSS as string:

```js
import stylesAsString from './my-styles.css'
```

My build script uses esbuild:

```js
esbuild
  .build({
    ...
    target: 'es2020',
    minify: true,
    loader: { '.css': 'text' },
    ...
  })
```

Everything is basically working, but of course the embedded CSS is not minified.
Is there a way with esbuild to embed CSS as text (as 'text' loader is doing) but also minify the embedded CSS first? TYVM

Answer (score 1):

I would give it a try with:

1. getting some post CSS plugin, they have multiple on the list ([1](https://github.com/deanc/esbuild-plugin-postcss), [2](https://github.com/martonlederer/esbuild-plugin-postcss2), [3](https://github.com/karolis-sh/esbuild-postcss)) which probably means each has some rough edges
2. [postcss-minify](https://www.npmjs.com/package/postcss-minify)

Answer (score 1):

Sounds like [Kingjin has an improved answer; you should check it out](https://stackoverflow.com/a/74134638/1485308).

---

I asked about this in a [GitHub issue on the esbuild repo](https://github.com/evanw/esbuild/issues/2609). The creator of esbuild helpfully replied with the following (untested) plugin code that provides CSS minification by calling esbuild from within the plugin's build step. Again, it's not tested, and this is all from the developer, not me. It certainly seems promising. (I do not have the cycles to test it right now, but am posting because it seems most likely to be a viable solution, given that it comes from the developer :-).)

```js
let yourPlugin = {
  name: 'your-plugin',
  setup(build) {
    build.onLoad({ ... }, async (args) => {
      let css = await fs.promises.readFile(args.path)
      css = await esbuild.transform(css, { loader: 'css', minify: true })
      return { loader: 'text', contents: css }
    })
  },
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Thanks, matatk!

It works (modified a little):

```js
import { Plugin, transform } from "esbuild"
import { readFile } from "fs/promises"

export const CSSMinifyPlugin: Plugin = {
    name: "CSSMinifyPlugin",
    setup(build) {
        build.onLoad({ filter: /\.css$/ }, async (args) => {
            const f = await readFile(args.path)
            const css = await transform(f, { loader: "css", minify: true })
            return { loader: "text", contents: css.code }
        })
    }
}
```